# Getting AttributeError: 'TopicPartition' object has no attribute '_jTopicAndPartition' when using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka

At first, I use the api,

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc=ssc,
                              topics=topics,
                              kafkaParams={"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
```

to consume kafka message, this way it works, but it always consume from the latest offset which is not what I want, so I change the api to

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc=ssc,
                              topics=topics,
                              kafkaParams={"metadata.broker.list": brokers},
                              fromOffsets=fromOffset,
                              messageHandler=messageHnadler)
```

which can set the `fromOffset`, but when I run the same programme I get the error below:

> File
>   "/Users/peterpan/Documents/software/spark-1.6.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py",
>   line 138, in createDirectStream AttributeError: 'TopicPartition'
>   object has no attribute '_jTopicAndPartition'

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was using wrong type of `fromOffsets`,

use

```
pyspark.streaming.kafka.TopicAndPartition
```

instead of

```
kafka.structs.TopicPartition
```